# Templates for Slack posts

Tags: slack

Is there a way to configure templates for Slack posts? e.g. I could type something like `/template hi` or just `/hi` and it would start the message with `Hello world nice day isn't it`, without actually posting it so I can edit the message.

Ideally, a library of templates would be available to the whole team to use and collaborate on. (We have some standard reporting and request formats this would be useful for.)

Comment: Did you find a workaround for this? looking for the same thing

Comment: No  Only option I know of might be to use one of the Slack-like apps that's more oriented around Trello-style project management, but I didn't investigate it.

Comment: Hard to believe they didn't think of that use-case!! I guess I can create a Slack app and add a few shortcuts like you suggested. But such an overkill!

Comment: I was also looking for a similar feature, seems so simple to me.

Comment: Rather than seeking something Slack specific, it'd probably be better to find something for your operating system. Like a dmenu keybinding or macro, then you can have a application-agnostic solution for templates.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried exactly what you're asking but I was able to use the API and write a post in a channel

https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload

This could get you closer to what you want it to do